LWC, pdf.js and fake workers
I am working in Salesforce Lightning Web Components. And trying to render the text of a pdf I upload. When I invoke the pdfjsLib.getDocument function it says that it will use a fake worker, even though I have set the worker in the initialization.  I have LWS set on. Is there something I'm missing from my understanding? The critical code is as below;
    Promise.all([loadScript(this, pdfjsLibzip + '/pdf.js'), loadScript(this, pdfjsLibzip + '/pdf.worker.js')])
        .then(() => {
            //pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsLibzip + '/pdf.worker.js';
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;
            console.log('pdf.js loaded successfully' + JSON.stringify(pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc));
            this.pdfjsLibLoaded = true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading pdf.js', error.message);
        });
}

async handleFileChange(event) {

    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file && file.type === 'application/pdf') {
        // Load the PDF file
        console.log('about to create file reader');
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = async () => {

            let loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: reader.result});
            //
            loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
                console.log('PDF loaded');
            });

